# Generate an array from smaller arrays using MPI

Tags: arrays, fortran, mpi

I would like to build a big array of dimensions (nx, ny, nz) starting from more smaller arrays of dimensions (nx, ny, nz/np), where np is the number of processors.

As I am new to MPI, I don't exactly know the best procedure. What I tried for now is this (fortran):

```
call mpi_sendrecv(u_small(nx, ny, nz/np), nx*ny*nz/np, rp, up, 1, u_tot(nx, ny,nz),nx*ny*nz, rp, down, 1, comm, status, ierr)
```

in which `rp`, `comm` and `status` are already properly defined and they're correct.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

You seem vague on how MPI works. "build a big array" where? On one of the processes? Then you need to use `MPI_Gather`.

But I have to ask: why? MPI is partly motivated by the need for oodles of memory. (In a pre-multicore world, a process was a processor, so the more processes, the more processors, and the more memory.) So a good MPI program keeps all its data distributed, and you "big array" is something that exists only in your mind. Besides: if you have enough processes, that "big array" may not even fit the memory of a single process. So: why do you want to construct it explicitly to being with?

Comment: Or possibly `MPI_Gatherv`. But I agree, keep things distributed - use of mpi_gather(v) usually indicates things are not being done in a good way.